# I would like to make my savings work for me: is the "Rich dad, poor dad" a good resource?

Tags: starting-out-investing, books, reference-material

I have one source of income (my job) and I've never been interested in investing. Now I need to, because my employer has been quite happy with my job and it has been rewarding me with RSO (Restricted Stock Options) for the last few years. Also, it looks like the right thing to do, because these RSO are order of magnitudes higher than the raises I get (base salaries in my country are *extremely* low, and raises are low even relatively to base salaries, so don't think anything like USA). I thus would like to learn more about managing my finances. Is the book in the title a good resource? Yes, no, why?

Ps the [starting-out-investing](/questions/tagged/starting-out-investing) tag seemed to me to be the [investing](/questions/tagged/investing) tag more closely related to my question, but maybe "how to manage my existing investments" would have been more appropriate...I say "maybe" because I'm completely new to the game and I have no idea if stocks must be kept for long time, must be sold for other stocks, etc. I have a general idea that this kind of investment only gives a return if kept for long periods (like 10 or more years),  while in the short term it's more likely to result in "losses", since it looks like a stochastic process with an increasing long-time trend but huge short and medium term up and downs. But that's basically all I understand about it.

PS2: apparently there are some pretty strong criticisms of the book:

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rich_Dad_Poor_Dad)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/74633/discussion-on-question-by-deltaiv-i-would-like-to-make-my-savings-work-for-me-i). Note - further comments will be removed with prejudice, and no notice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The book is more of a motivational book with a tilt towards owning real estate. It was an interesting read but if you are looking to learn about stock trading then it isn't a good resource. Kiyosaki is a bit anti-establishment.

Comment: Yes. He thinks 'buying the dip' is not as good as real estate, but he illustrates that the conventional wisdom to be focused primarily on your career is not always your best option.